# os x gui api clarification

Tags: user-interface, macos, window-managers

If I wanted to write my own window manager for OS X (please dont respond with "whats the point"??), what APIs should I be looking at?

Comment: To replace the OS X window server or to run in the X Windows environment?

Comment: Well this is where the original problem comes from.. I thought X couldnt display cocoa apps ?

Comment: You cannot run Cocoa apps in an X window server. It sounds like you want to replace the OS X WindowServer process.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "window manager" in OS X, and no public interface to implement one.  The functions that an X11 window manager would perform are split between the GUI toolkit (Carbon/Cocoa), the Dock application and the window server.

Your only real choice if you want to change OS X's windowing behavior is to patch individual applications, the Dock (which has a privileged connection to the window server) and/or the window server.  It'd involve a great deal of reverse engineering and almost certainly break in 10.6, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Clearly this is possible, given the existence of commercial tools like http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/.  What are the window server APIs like?

Comment: SizeUp works by using a combination of accessibility and scripting interfaces. It doesn't modify existing windowing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

At the hardware level, write your own APIs.

Otherwise, there are various [graphics architectures](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/architecture/index.html) in which to plug in your window manager:

- [OpenGL](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/)
- [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/quartz/)
- [Quicktime](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/)
- [X11](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/X11.html)

Comment: ok cool, i was pretty sure quartz is what i wanted to look at.  thanks for confirmation